# installed group policy editor win10 home missing "power management" folder

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I used this guide to install the policy editor. 
[Missing folders in gpedit.msc](https://superuser.com/questions/1064229/missing-folders-in-gpedit-msc?newreg=c563007f0f294dc4ba47b9baa6c4f229) 
Everything was fine until I looked for the power management folder. It isn't there.
I'm trying to use this method 
[https://www.windowscentral.com/how-prevent-windows-10-requiring-password-when-resuming-sleepto](https://forums.windowscentral.com/windows-central-news-discussion/442950-how-prevent-windows-10-requiring-password-when-resuming-sleep.html?_ga=2.160408446.256889929.1501176231-1698135603.1501176231) turn off password on wake from sleep in win10.

Comment: It appears that you pasted the link incorrectly, because when I click it the WindowsCentral.com site says the page cannot be found. Please get the correct link and use the EDIT button below your question to fix the link.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are not running as a local admin. I checked few of my devices and when I am local admin, I see those folders:
[image]

When I am not, they are not there. Post screenshot from your GPO editor with root expanded...